# svcutil with local files dosen't make code but online does

Tags: c#, web-services, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have locally a wsdl it's xsd's files and trying to get the proxy file with `svcutil.exe` with this command

```
svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /l:cs
```

I get this error:

> Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
>
> Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: 
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>
> Error: There was a problem loading the XSD documents provided: a reference to a schema element with name 'callcreditheaders' and namespace 'urn:xxxx/yyyy:zzzz' could not be resolved because the element definition could not be found in the schema for targetNamespace 'urn:xxxx/yyyy:zzzz'.
>
> Please check the XSD documents provided and try again.
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   `//wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:xxxx/yyyy:zzzz']/wsdl:portType[@name='Soap']`

But if I put that files in my local IIS on an Web Application and use this command

```
svcutil [http://localhost/XX/YY.wsdl] /l:cs
```

It works.

Why svcutil work different even they are the same files?, and is there any way to work this with the local call?